# The name something does not exists in the current context with static class

Tags: c#, reference, static

I have a Logger that I've pout into a static class.

I want to be albe to call the (static) methods of this class in all my app layers.

Here, My business layer (portable class), I use normal classes with static methods but I can't call my Logger, the name LOGGER does not exists in the current context.

I have a reference to the Logger project, but there is a warning icon on the reference. There is no paht on the properties of the reference, but I really added the reference by clicking on Project then the project that contains the logger.

Call to Logging:

```
public class AnomalyBL
    {
        private static Container<IList<Anomaly>> MyMethod()
        {
            try
            {
                something
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string errorMsg = string.Format("text ({0})", ex.Message);
                Logger.MyLogger.LogError(ex, errorMsg);
            }
            return container;
        }
}
```

Logger:

```
namespace Logger{
public static class MyLogger
    {

        public static bool LogError(Exception ex, string message = "")
        {
            try
            {
                GetLogger().Log(LogLevel.Error, ex, message);
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
}
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is your static class public? A missing accessor on a class will be treated as an internal class so only visible in the project it is declared in. It would also help to post some code so we don't have to ask or guess these things.

Comment: @Igor no. Chekc my new answer, I've added the requested code :-) thanks

Comment: Don't ignore the warning, whatever it looks like.  *Exactly* quoting the messages in the Error List window is essential to get a correct answer.

Comment: @Hans you're right, I didn't check them, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several reasons why references might not work and have that warning icon:
First try to remove the reference, then add it again: Say you have project A that should refer to project B which contains Logger. In solution explorer, in project A right click on References -> add reference -> solution -> Project B

If the new reference is still showing the warning, then there should be a problem like: 
The .net version in project B is Higher than A,
Or the platforms do not match, for instance project B targets .Net framework and A is a silverlight project.
In the errors window, click on warnings icon to see the warnings, there should be one which explains the reason why project B cannot be referenced from A